# Model "if and only if" indicator constraints in Linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

Apologies if this question has been asked, but I haven't been able to find it. I'm modelling something with Gurobi and want to do the following:

\begin{align}\text{cond} < \dfrac{1}{3} &\iff x = 1,\\\dfrac{1}{3} \leq \text{cond} \leq \dfrac{2}{3} &\iff y = 1,\\\dfrac{2}{3} <\text{cond}\leq 1 &\iff z = 1\end{align}
$$ (x,y,z) \in \{0,1\}^{3}, 0\leq \text{cond}\leq 1$$

So, three indicator variables depending on $\text{cond}$. I managed to model the left implications (e.g. $\text{cond}\leq \dfrac{1}{3} + 2(1-x)$), but I'm having a bit of trouble with the right side and making sure it all ties together.

Comment: It is substantially more complicated than what I was thinking, but I found a paper "Nonconvex piecewise linear functions: Advanced formulations and simple modeling tools" that also answers this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without using a small epsilon, you can’t enforce strict inequality.  Here’s one approach that allows ambiguity at the endpoints of each interval, as your proposed constraint does:
$$
x+y+z=1\\
0x+\frac{1}{3}y+\frac{2}{3}z
\le \text{cond} \le
\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}y+1z
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried quite a bit and got nowhere, do you mind telling me how you reached this solution? How does one generally approach this?

Comment: Glad to help.  Not sure where I first learned this approach, but I suggested it [here](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2015/02/partitioning-with-binary-variables.html#comment-form) for a very similar situation.  I also recommend watching the linearization and modeling tags, for which some posts link to additional resources.